# Running a VPN server and a captive portal on the same machine with a DNS too

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, ipsec, captive-portal

I don't know if this can be done but I'm asking anyways.

Let's say that I've an Ubuntu machine with OpenSwan and xl2ptd to handle incoming VPN connections.

Now, what I need to do is something like forcing every user to accept some conditions on a page before starting the navigation.

So the user must be connected to the VPN and has also to be authenticated with this kind of captive portal (which will not be used for pure authentication but just to forse the user to read and accept the ToS before using the service).

As an extra, the page shoul be coming from a custom name domani (which is not registered) so that the user will see `www.mydomain.com/tos`.
This requires a DNS server on my machine and I've got to setup the VPN to use 127.0.0.1 as a DNS.

So the question is:
is there any way to have a VPN, a captive portal and a DNS server on the same machine and have them work together?

So that the traffic has to follow these routes:

```
(First connection)
user --> vpn --> captive portal with custom domain from my DNS
(other times)
user --> vpn --> internet using the same DNS as before that forwards unknown entries to an external one
```

I've found an article about `Chillispot` with `OpenSwan` but I'm not using a `RADIUS` server to authenticate my users to the VPN and I don't know if there's a way to make Chillispot work without RADIUS.